# VBA Text to Columns FieldInfo Text not working

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am trying to create a code which converts column A to columns with a | delimiter and want column A to be in Text format.

My code:

```
Sub TEST_Text_to_Columns()
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, _
      OtherChar:="|"
      FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


ActiveSheet.Columns("A:GZ").AutoFit


End Sub
```

It doesn't seem to like this at the FieldInfo part.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `, _` after `OtherChar` line:

```
Sub TEST_Text_to_Columns()
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, _
      OtherChar:="|", _
      FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


ActiveSheet.Columns("A:GZ").AutoFit


End Sub
```

However, to also fix the rest of the code:

- Select and selection are unnecessary, slow things down and can cause errors. There are articles in this forum as to how and why to avoid them.
- To format a column as text, `xlTextFormat` returns a `2`, so your `FieldInfo` should be a bit different:

---

```
Sub TEST_Text_to_Columns()
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, _
      OtherChar:="|", _
      FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


ActiveSheet.Columns("A:GZ").AutoFit


End Sub
```